# Sort of like concatenation but not quite

Tags: python, concatenation

```
for seqA in poolA:
    print seqA + ":",
    for i in seqA:
        print complements[i],
    print
```

`complements` is a `dict` and `poolA` is a `list`.

When I `print complements[i]` there are spaces in between, how do I remove these spaces?

Answer (score 5):

Join the items and print the resulting string.

```
print ''.join(str(complements[i]) for i in seqA)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, just don't print them out. Use either `from __future__ import print_function` and then `print(complements[i], end = '')`, or `sys.stdout.write(complements[i])`.